# How do I make a single responsive background image with css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a background image for a div:

```
<div class="wrap">

</div>
```

And here is the `css`:

```
.wrap {
    background-image: url("woody.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Why do I have to set a height?  How come it won't use the height of the image?  How do I create just a single image and not have it repeat over and over? And keep it responsive? Also, how do I have it stretch the full width of the screen and not max out with the image size?

Answer (score 0):

Depends of where are you using the wrapper, but if you use position relative have to set a height since with `height: auto` it will take the height of the children. Maybe setting an min-height would be a fix, but depends of the context.

```
.wrap {
    background-image: url("woody.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first: You call your background an "image", but in fact it is not. It is just a background, that does not affect flow and has no representation in DOM tree. So you could just write `background:red` and expect the same.

And now:

- You have to set the height, because wrapping div does not know what it has inside, for browser there is really nothing physically.
- thus browser won't use height of image, because it's not an physical image, it's not computed by the layout engine
- there is possibility to have it trully responsive, you just have to know the proportion of an image, if we assume it's 2:1, then you could write something like `height:50vw`, but after all I would not recommend this.
- what I would do in this situation... if I can't expect image size proportions, then would probably put an image in there with something like `img{display:block;width:100%;height:auto;}`, if you will make some demo on jsfiddle, we can play with it.